# QNX gdb server to debug a application

Tags: gdb, qnx

Nowdays I use qnx gdb server to debug a application, but there are some amazing things happend.

There are lots of files in my project, for examples

```
src/a.c src/b.c src/c.c
include/a.h include/b.h include/c.h
```

using Makefile, I generate a libso file named `libtest.so` and a executable file name `helloworld`.

I scp the `libtest.so` and `helloworld` to target machine, and the path is `/home/user/myapp/` and set `PATH` well, and I can run `helloworld` in target machine

Attention there is a fun name `Display()` fun in the `libtest.so`, and there is a fuction named `myfun()` in the i`nclude/c.h`(at line 5), and `myfun` will call `Dislpay()` function:

```
myfun(){Display();}
```

When I use qnx gdb server , the step is as follows:

```
  1. ntoaarch64-gdb
  2. file helloworld
  3. target qnx IP:PORT
  4. upload helloworld /home/user/helloworld
  5. b c.h:5 
  6. r
```

It call stop at breakpoint `myfun()`, but when I run `step` or `stepi` command,
it can not step into `Display()` function, and I run `disassemble`command,
it show `0x100cd5e0 <Display@plt>`, There is no disassembly content about `Display` function, I seemed be omitted!

There are any worng or missing step when I debug this application, who can help my, I have speed five days... Thank a lot

By the way, I think is a gdb server question instead of a qnx gdb server question.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I run `step` or `stepi` command, it can not step into `Display()` function

This is somewhat expected with lazy dynamic symbol resolution. Note that if you call `myfun` *again*, you should be able to `step` into `Display` without problems.

The best solution is to set a `break Display`.

Alternatively, you could use `export LD_BIND_NOW=1` before running `helloworld`, or link the binary with `-Wl,-z,now` to disable lazy symbol binding.

Comment: Hi,if I call myfun again, I could not step into Display() function also. I think there is something wrong with gdb server.